# Convert time into HH:mm:ss formate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, datetimepicker

I am converting time into this formate (HH:mm:ss) but I am getting response nil. Here I attached my complete code please give some suggestion.

```
// This is my time
let setDate = "2000-01-01 12:04:00 UTC"

// Conversion in seconds
    let secondsConvert = manyServiceTime*60*60
    print(secondsConvert)

 // Time Interval
let datebbb = setDate!.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(secondsConvert))
    print(datebbb)

 //this is I am getting date with am/pm
let formatterEnd = DateFormatter()
    formatterEnd.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    formatterEnd.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let settime1 = formatterEnd.string(from: datebbb)
    print(settime1)

//now here I am converting into hours minutes and seconds. 
let formatEnd = DateFormatter()
    formatEnd.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let endTimeSet = formatEnd.string(from: datebbb)
    print(endTimeSet)
```

Comment: Try Using 'formatEnd.dateFormat = "H:mm:ss"'

Comment: let setDate = "2000-01-01 12:04:00 UTC" is String OR Date?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, I made `setDate` into a Date type and everything works fine.

Comment: setDate is a string how do you expect string to have a method `addingTimeInterval`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only time use this code
I've created a extension that returns the time in string

```
extension String {

  func formatDate() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let dateFromStr = formatter.date(from: self)

    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let endTimeSet = formatter.string(from: dateFromStr!)
    print(endTimeSet)
    return endTimeSet
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let setDate = "2000-01-01 12:04:00"
let timeOnly = setDate.formatDate()
```

Comment: It won't work reliably if you don't also set locale to `POSIX`.